# WPF: How add check mark to the textblock?

Tags: wpf, character-encoding

I am wondering if anyone knows the tag for check mark symbol. I need to have it in a texblock. I looked online for any clue and did not find anything that will work with XAML.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just refer this document by Josh smith about
 ***Differences between Label and TextBlock***

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/

I think you can do by using Label

```
<Label>   
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
<Path 
                                Width="11" Height="11" 

                                SnapsToDevicePixels="False" 
                                Stroke="red"
                                StrokeThickness="2"
                                Data="M 2,4 C 2,4 3,5 5,13 C 5,13 5,3 12,0" />
                                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Successfully Completed!</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                </Label>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use the SQUARE ROOT character in either in XAML or code-behind to achieve a check mark symbol:

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="√"/>
    <TextBox Text="√"/>
    <Label Content="√"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
txtBoxName.Text = "\x221A";
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I ended up drawing a path for check mark. The method above did render checkmark. Perphaps, I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
   <TextBlock Text="&#xE10B;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"/>
   <Border Width="10"/>
   <TextBlock Text="Checkmark!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"/>
</StackPanel>
```