# Symbols, Special character display issue in wpf

Tags: wpf, special-characters

In WPF text block, I want to display special characters like diamond (♦) etc. It is displaying fine in some systems and in some systems, it is displaying a plain box instead of the symbol.

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

-Elangovan.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: How add check mark to the textblock?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623766/wpf-how-add-check-mark-to-the-textblock)

Answer (score 0):

When you want "special characters" you should probably use images instead of depending on fonts. For one thing, you have no guarantee that the user will have the font you use.